# Multilanguage in Symfony2 and Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, multilingual

how to create multilanguage page in  Symfony? In Symfony 1.0, Jobeet tutorial has very good description. But now on symfony.com, i haven't seen somethings related to translation of page.
In symfony 1.4, echo __('text'); is used, but now in Symfony 2 TWIG is used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a documentation section on this on the Symfony2 website.

You can check it here: [Translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

Basically, you have access in the routing to a special attribute named `_locale` that is put in your url and will be used to set the locale in the session. Note that using this scheme, the locale value is automatically set into the `Session` by Symfony2

```
http://www.host.com/en/contact // English version
http://www.host.com/fr/contact // French version
```

You can also specify a default `_locale` value in your routes so it is not mandatory to provide the locale in the url.

```
http://www.host.com/contact    // English version if default _locale is 'en'
```

Then, in twig, you use the special transformer `trans` and `transchoice` to translate messages. Your messages can be a key or an natural language message that is used as the key, usually in english.

```
{{ 'user.prompt.welcome' | trans }} {# Key message #}
{{ 'Welcome to our site' | trans }} {# Natural language message #}
```

The locale to translate the message is taken from the session, so changing the locale in the session (via the url or programmaticaly), will change the translation to another thing.

This uses the `translator` service under the hood.

Comment: @mario Please read Symfony documentation about Translations (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) for this. The question was at a higher level of abstraction than how to use the translation system, cheers.

Comment: Why was '@Matt' erased by above comment?