# How to implement multilanguage in Twig?

Tags: twig, multilingual

How to implement multilanguage in Twig templates?

Before using Twig, I used gettext function to implement multilanguage, but I don't know if there is any way to call this function from a twig template.

The most related I found about this, is this question, that talks about twig and symfony, but in my case I'm using only Twig lib:

[Multilanguage in Symfony2 and Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271125/multilanguage-in-symfony2-and-twig)

I've looked for functions/attributes "trans" in twig documentation but I found nothing.

Is there any function? Or I have to duplicate every template for every language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

### [The i18n Extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html)

"The i18n extension adds [gettext](http://www.php.net/gettext) support to Twig. It defines one tag, trans."

### Usage

```
{% trans "Hello World!" %}

{% trans string_var %}

{% trans %}
    Hello World!
{% endtrans %}
```